# Perpendiculars and distance

Tags: geometry

COORDINATE GEOMETRY Find the distance from P to L.
4. Line L contains points (-2,0) and (4,8). Point P has coordinates (5,1)

Can you help me solve this with work I can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried and where you are getting stuck. That way, people on this site will know exactly what help you need.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  The distance will be along a line from P that is perpendicular to L.  You need the fact that perpendicular lines have slopes that are negative inverses.  So calculate the slope of L, divide it into $-1$, put a line through P with that slope, find where it intersects L, and compute the distance from P to the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Form the equation of the line L using two point form

$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ where $m=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$

Suppose you get a line, wrote it in the form $Ax+By+C=0$

Then find the shortest distance of point P(5,1) from that the line L using the formula

$$d=\frac{|Ax_1+By_1+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

Here $x_1=5$ and $y_1=1$

Comment: To write $x_1$ type x_1 between dollar signs.  To type $\sqrt{x}$, type \sqrt{x} between dollar signs.  To type $\frac{a}{b}$, type \frac{a}{b} between dollar signs.  This [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.